# passing arguments succinctly when the number of arguments is unknown

Tags: r

Many R functions take a variable number of arguments.  `sum()` is an example: `sum(1, 2)`, `sum(1, 2, 3)`, and `sum(1, 2, 3, 4)` are all valid commands.

I need to write scripts that run in batch mode.  In these scripts, I need to pass multiple arguments to a function.  The arguments will not be passed in from the command line.  They must be variables (not strings corresponding to variable names).  They will all be of the same class, and their names will start with the same characters, but I won't know the names or the number of arguments.  Is there a succinct way to pass the variables to the function?

Here is an example: I want code the yields the sum of all variables whose names have the pattern `^int\\d$`.  I know that there is at least one such variable, but I don't know how many  there are.  This code works:

```
# Set up toy data
int1 <- 3
int2 <- 5

# Get the sum
argNames <- ls(pat='^int\\d$')
argNames.list <- as.list(argNames)
argNames.list <- lapply(argNames.list, function (x) get(x))
do.call(sum, argNames.list)
```

My objection is that this code is a little cumbersome.  Spreading the operation out over four lines reduces clarity.  Is there an R-idiomatic way to get the same result with fewer lines of code?

Comment: You could make sure all the variables you want are contained in a specific environment, and use `?eapply`

Comment: If you'll be running this in batch mode, you can get access to the arguments with `commandArgs`.

Comment: @RomanLustrik -- thank you.  But `commandArgs` doesn't help me here: the script will be run in batch mode, but the arguments won't be passed from the command line.

Comment: I guess my assumption was wrong, my bad. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Edited to better address the question)**

I don't think you can do much better than this, which seems pretty minimal to me.

```
int1 <- 3
int2 <- 5

do.call(sum, lapply(ls(pat="^int\\d$"), get))
# [1] 8

## Or use a safer version that will only look for objects located in the 
## environment from which it was called.  
do.call(sum, lapply(ls(pat="^int\\d$"), get, envir=parent.frame(), inherits=FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful -- but it doesn't seem any more succinct.  Even after defining `flexFun`, it seems that I'll still need to use four lines of code, because I don't know the names of the variables that I'll be passing to `flexFun`.  Is that correct, or am I missing something?  (The function that I'm dealing with requires that its arguments be variables of a special class, not strings corresponding to variable names.  I'll edit the original post to add this detail.)

Comment: Were you after something more like this?

Answer (score 5):

This is slightly simpler encapsulating it all in a function and eliminating `lapply` and `get`.  `ix` holds the indexes of the matching names.

```
# sum those arguments whose names match ^int\\d$
sumint <- function(...) {
    arg.names <- as.character(match.call()[-1])
    ix <- grep("^int\\d$", arg.names)
    do.call("sum", list(...)[ix])
}

# test    
a <- b <- 10
int3 <- 30
sumint(a, int3, b, int3, b, pi) # 60
```